# How do I keep two labels from overlapping, but have a dynamic width?

Tags: uilabel, constraints, uicollectionviewcell, swift4

I have two labels on the opposite sides of a `UICollectionViewCell` that both have dynamic widths. As seen in the screenshot bellow, the "Cream Cheese" and "$15.79" are automatically overlapping because of their dynamic widths.

[image: Cream Cheese and $15.79 Overlapping]

I want to keep both of those label's dynamic widths, but if the two come into contact, I want the label on the right of the `UICollectionViewCell` to be the preferred label. That would mean that the width of the label on the right is minimized depending on the dynamic width of the right label. Does anyone know of any ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Forget about using constraints for that. You should use stackviews

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this through **Interface Builder**, you should have **a constraint for horizontal spacing** between the two labels...

[image: horizontal spacing between the two labels]

...and give **a higher content compression resistance** for the label on the right.

[image: higher content compression resistance for the label on the right]

That way, it will expand and the longer label will have a shorter width, just as you'd expect.

Comment: This looks like it would work, but instead of having the desired result they both stay the same width.